# ASP.NET Core Custom authorization handler not triggering

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to setup a custom authorization handler in my project closely following the Resource-based authorization in ASP.NET Core Microsoft documentation. However, calling the API endpoint always returns a 403 response and doesn't even trigger a breakpoint in my handler.

Feels like I quadruple checked every single thing yet it still doesn't work. Am I blind or is there something wrong with my code?

Here's my custom handler:

```
public class TripAuthorizationHandler : AuthorizationHandler<SameUserRequirement, Trip>
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, SameUserRequirement requirement, Trip resource)
    {
        if(context.User.FindFirst("userId").Value == resource.ApplicationUserId)
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
public class SameUserRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement{}
```

Program.cs file:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = false,
        ValidateAudience = false,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["JWT:Issuer"],
        ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["JWT:Audience"],
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["JWT:Key"]))
    };
});

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("SameUser", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new SameUserRequirement()));
});

builder.Services.AddTransient<IAuthorizationHandler, TripAuthorizationHandler>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IAuthenticationService, AuthenticationService>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<ITokenService, TokenService>();

builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Program));

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseMiddleware<ExceptionHandlingMiddleware>();

app.UseAuthentication();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

And here's the controller:

```
    [Authorize(Policy = "SameUser")]
    [HttpPut("trips/{tripId}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateTrip([FromBody] TripPostDto request, int tripId)
    {
        var trip = await _tripService.GetByIdAsync(tripId);

         var authorizationResult = await _authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(User, trip, "SameUser");

        if (authorizationResult.Succeeded)
        {
            await _tripService.UpdateAsync(tripId, request);

            return NoContent();
        }
        else if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return Forbid();
        }
        else
        {
            return Challenge();
        }
    }
```

Edit:
Here's my implementation of AuthenticationService

```
public class AuthenticationService : IAuthenticationService
    {
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
        private readonly ITokenService _tokenService;
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;

        public AuthenticationService(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, IMapper mapper, ITokenService tokenService)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _mapper = mapper;
            _tokenService = tokenService;
        }

        public async Task<SuccessfulLoginDto> LoginAsync(LoginUserDto loginUserDto)
        {
            var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(loginUserDto.Email);

            if(user == null)
            {
                throw new ValidationException("Invalid login data!");
            }

            var passwordValid = await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, loginUserDto.Password);

            if (!passwordValid)
            {
                throw new ValidationException("Invalid login data!");
            }

            var accessToken =  await _tokenService.GetTokenAsync(user);

            return new SuccessfulLoginDto() { Token = accessToken.AccessToken };
        }

        public async Task RegisterAsync(RegisterUserDto registerUserDto)
        {
            var existingUser = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(registerUserDto.Email);

            if (existingUser != null)
            {
                throw new UserAlreadyExistsException("User with this email already exists!");
            }

            var newUser = _mapper.Map<ApplicationUser>(registerUserDto);

            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(newUser, registerUserDto.Password);

            if (!result.Succeeded)
            {
                throw new ValidationException(string.Join(" ", result.Errors.Select(e => e.Description)));
            }

            await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(newUser, Authorization.Roles.User.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you remove the Authorize tag does it hit your method?

Comment: @GHDevOps Controller method does trigger without the Authorize attribute. I also tested it with an empty Authorize attribute and in both cases it triggers the controller but the AuthorizeAsync returns false and still the handler is not getting triggered.

Comment: have you written your own implementation of `AuthenticationService`. as i can see you have explicitly registered it. when I followed the same [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/resourcebased?view=aspnetcore-6.0). I am able to hit the handler without any issue. remove `builder.Services.AddTransient<IAuthenticationService, AuthenticationService>();` if you are not writing your own.

Comment: I don't find anything  wrong in your code, But One thing different is: `builder.Services.AddTransient<IAuthenticationService, AuthenticationService>();`,In normal situation we don't need to register it, Can you explain about it and show code in `AuthenticationService`?

Comment: @XinranShen I have my own implementation of AuthenticationService which I use for handling user registration and login. Tried renaming it to AuthSevice but still the same problem. Edited my post to include the code.

Comment: If you don't the custom `IAuthenticationService`, Can the project work fine?

Comment: @XinranShen The IAuthenticationService is my own interface. I tried renaming it to something different but it still doesn't work. If I don't register it, I couldn't generate the JWT token needed to authenticate. To clarify, neither the controller method, nor the handler is getting called when the Authorize attribute with a policy is added but a 403 is returned instead.

Comment: I create a demo to test it and It work normally, So i think your custom `IAuthenticationService` maybe cause the error.

Comment: Did you find any resolution to your issue? I am currently experiencing a somewhat similar issue, I have an MVC controller method with a custom authorize attribute, but the authorization handler associated with that custome authorize attribute (which is also a requirement) is not invoked.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried ordering the service injection before?
Order matters in Startup

```cs
builder.Services.AddTransient<IAuthorizationHandler, TripAuthorizationHandler>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IAuthenticationService, AuthenticationService>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<ITokenService, TokenService>();
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = false,
        ValidateAudience = false,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["JWT:Issuer"],
        ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["JWT:Audience"],
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["JWT:Key"]))
    };
});

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("SameUser", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new SameUserRequirement()));
});
```

Comment: Order only when it comes to middleware.